# Jquery - Increase price

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to increase product-price by + 200 in the text. Important thing is the currency next to the price number needs to stay there.

```
<div class="col-md-4 product text-center" style="display: 
  <a href="/product/vintage-stribrne-pirko">
    <div class="product-img" style="background: ...') center center no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="product-title">
    <a href="/product/vintage-stribrne-pirko">Vintage stříbrné pírko</a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-price"> 490  Kč</div>
</div>
```

My Jquery code that works only if I put productPrice into console.log:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
  $('.product').each(function() {
  var productPrice = parseInt($(this).find('.product-price').text()) + 2000;
  $(productPrice).text();
  });
});
```

Thank you very much. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is `$(productPrice).text()` supposed to do?

Comment: it supposed to increase the price in html by 200 Kč (200 + 490)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you?

So we get the price from the div using JQuery and strip the currency and finally add the value to show the result in another div with class `output`, please let me know if this fixes your issue!

```js
$(document).ready(function($) { 
  var price = 0;
  $('.product').each(function() {
  price += parseInt($(this).find('.product-price').text().replace("Kč", "").replace(" ", ""))  + 2000;
  });
  $(".output").text(price + " Kč");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 product text-center">
  <a href="/product/vintage-stribrne-pirko">
    <div class="product-img">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="product-title">
    <a href="/product/vintage-stribrne-pirko">Vintage stříbrné pírko</a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-price"> 490  Kč</div>
</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(productPrice).text();
```

You're confusing things here. You're supposed to pass the new value to `text()`, not the selector.

What you mean is:

```
$('.product-price').text(productPrice);
```

Calling `text()` without a argument returns the current value; calling it with one sets a new value.

Comment: `$(productPrice).text(productPrice);` Check that one over.

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's make it simple

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
  $('.product').each(function() {
  var ProductPriceElement = $(this).find('.product-price'), // the product-price element
      producttext = ProductPriceElement.text(), // element text
      productPrice = parseInt(producttext),    // element price number
      productPricePlus200 = productPrice + 200;  // add 200 to the price number
  var NewTextReplace = producttext.replace(productPrice , productPricePlus200); // replace the old price with the new one
  ProductPriceElement.text(NewTextReplace); // change the element text with the new one
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 product text-center" style="display: block">
  <a href="/product/vintage-stribrne-pirko">
    <div class="product-img" style="background: ...') center center no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="product-title">
    <a href="/product/vintage-stribrne-pirko">Vintage stříbrné pírko</a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-price"> 490  Kč</div>
</div>
```